# How to search for texts

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a particular column in a table where staff narrates the nature of payment or receipt.

Write something like `'PAYMENT OF SALARIES FOR THE MONTH OF NOVEMBER 2018'`.I want to be able to have code (ORACLE SQL) that will just pick the months out of those narrations.

Comment: Please add some code and data to your question, to make it complete.

Answer (score 1):

*You can use regexp-based functions (_replace,_substr,_count) consecutively to extract the month name, assuming all data with the same format model as ending with "month year" combination*

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'PAYMENT OF SALARIES FOR THE MONTH OF NOVEMBER 2018' from dual
), t2 as
(
select rtrim(str,regexp_replace(str,'(\D)')) as str       
  from t
), t3 as
(  
select regexp_substr(str,'[^ ]+',1,level) as str, 
       regexp_count(str,'[^ ]+') as cnt,
       level as lvl 
  from t2
 connect by level <= regexp_count(str,'[^ ]+')
)
select str 
  from t3 
 where lvl = cnt;

STR
--------
NOVEMBER
```

Comment: but thata manipulation could have been done using substr(insrt()) and all if the given text format is specified

Comment: @nikhilsugandh thanks, you're right, that's another method.

Comment: @nikhilsugandh rather than hardcoding(8th), the last row may be preferable to use.

Comment: Ozhan its all the same you are just changing the words in the sentence although gave it an upvote!!!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh by the way, due to the number of the words, you might consider 9 as the fixed value, and that yields `2018`

Answer (score 0):

even this will work as the text format you specified is same :

```
 select * from (select rownum, regexp_substr("column1",'[^ ]+', 1, level) from Table1
 connect by regexp_substr("column1", '[^ ]+', 1, level) is not null) where rownum<=8
 minus
 select * from (select rownum, regexp_substr("column1",'[^ ]+', 1, level) from Table1
 connect by regexp_substr("column1", '[^ ]+', 1, level) is not null) where rownum<8;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/560dc/13

Answer (score 0):

```
 where
  Date >= to_date(substr(:from_date ,1,10),'YYYY/MM/DD') 
  and 
  Date <= to_date(substr(:last_date,1,10),'YYYY/MM/DD')
```